# Loading series of strings using Array in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, nsarray

I have a series of simple sentences e.g. "Hi", "How are you?", "I am fine", "Nice to see you".

I would like to store them in an array. 
The problem is I want to display only the first sentence in a single textview. Then when I press a button, it display the second sentence. 
So i want it display each of the sentences after a button press.

Which kind of array i should use and how to code it?
Many Thanks

Comment: is this homework? what have you tried? you can start with an `NSArray` or just put the strings in array like `@[@"Hi", @"How are you?", @"I am fine", @"Nice to see you"]`

Comment: Use `NSArray` if you won't change your array after the initialization, or use `NSMutableArray`. Call [objectAtIndex:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/objectAtIndex:) to access your sentence.

Comment: But how can i use UIButton to switch each the sentences?

Comment: Remember index of the sentence being shown. Increment it with every tap.  Pass this index to objectAtIndex as suggested by WangYudong. You will have to check for total number of sentences in the array. If you try to access more than the array holds you will get an array index out of bounds exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an NSMutable array that will hold all of your strings. 
Set the tag of all the buttons starting from 0 to i less than the size of array which will act as an index for the array. 
 Then when you click on any button use the tag of button to access the array contents at that particular index.